# How to make force sensitive resistor energy efficient?

Tags: circuit-design, switches, embedded, components, low-power

I'm trying to sense when pressure stops being applied between two surfaces with a small embedded device connected to a coin battery smaller than 50mAh. All I care about is if they're separated or not (and this triggers waking up from hibernation).

Up until now I've been using a [force sensitive resistor](https://learn.adafruit.com/force-sensitive-resistor-fsr) and that has worked great...except the battery life is around 1 week using this method since the resistor closes the circuit when force is applied, and 99.999% of the time the surfaces will be together. The circuit consumption is around .13 mA while the force resistor is closed and .0014 mA when it's open....so a huge difference in battery life.

Is there a way to make this system more energy efficient? The thickness of the force sensitive resistor (.5mm) is about as thick as I can fit between the surfaces. A normally closed limit switch or force sensitive resistor would be exactly what I need, but I'm not aware of any that exist at this size

Comment: What order of force is "on"?

Comment: @RussellMcMahon I don't know the exact pounds of force or anything, but with the force resistor it's anything >28 out of a scale from 0-31. Maybe 1-2lbs of force typically when the surfaces are together...

Comment: Tactile dome switches are used in many cheap keyboards. || I said 10 uA based on a 1  megohm resistor and some leeway. On a 5V supply with 10 megohms it's 0.5 uA. That may work depending on input pin characteristics and a reasonable environment.

Comment: You could make a custom see-saw type switch where pressure opens the contact. Or a magnet and reed switch. Knowing more about the physical environment would help.

Comment: @RussellMcMahon The thickness needs to stay around .5mm or less, do you have an example of the custom see-saw switch you're thinking of? I was considering a hall effect sensor for a bit like you brought up, but I'm not sure if there are any that are small enough with an insignificant power draw while the surfaces are together

Comment: I could draw a picture, but I "thought that up" on the spot. It definitely doable. 0.5mm is annoyingly small. Can you raise the height allowance. One method. You have a rocking pad pivoted at one edge. WHen pressed it lies flat. Te edge opposite the pivot presses on a "seesaw" with a mechanical advantage of whatever you wish to raisw the other end. The far end contact coud be mechnical or a reed switch wit zero power drain. || You could use pneumatic or hydraulic coupling. || A dome tact switch is easyish and current depends on max resistance you can support. well under 1 uA.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've since switched to using a Piezoelectric buzzer, it doesn't require any power connection and can be tuned to the specific desired force with a resistor. It's also cheaper and more customizable.

Answer (score 5):

> *Is there a way to make this system more energy efficient?*

If you are not bothered about determining the pressure immediately, you can turn off the resistive sensor for 99% (or more) of the time and, for 1% of the time take a measurement. This immediately reduces the current consumption to one-hundredth of what you currently have. This sort of trick is bread and butter to most analogue EEs. A similar example is when a battery powered device needs to check its battery voltage; a potential divider feeding an MCU's ADC is always taking current from the battery but, if that potential divider is "open-circuited" with a MOSFET (when not in-use), power savings are obvious.

So, turn on for as long as it takes to make a measurement then disable the circuit for as long as possible i.e. measure for 10 ms then sleep for 990 ms. This will reduce the time that the heavier current is being drawn significantly.

Comment: Sorry, should have given more information about the timing. In this case I'm trying to monitor the surfaces 24/7, and I expect them to be separated for as little as 80ms before coming back together. The frequency of separation is anywhere between 10 times a day to 1 time a week and I need the mcu to catch each. 

The power consumption is around 30 uA waking up ~6ms every 44ms....so still 20x higher than the device staying in hibernation

Comment: You need to be less ambiguous about your requirements. Draw a timing diagram of the pulse and clearly explain how long the MCU is active. I got lost reading your comment. You can still modulate the current into the sensor. You can do it at a high rate so you have at least one "active" incident in 80 ms. So if you turn on the resistor for 800 microseconds every 80 milliseconds you get 100:1 current reduction still. Now, you paint a picture around that proposal. Also state whether all daily ten events are contiguous. Think about it more. Fit the power downs into where you know they can fit.

Answer (score 2):

Adding a series resistor will reduce current and voltage swing. Using a comparator to detect voltage swing could reduce consumption to comparator quiescent current.

A tactile dome switch will allow on,/off operation at say around 10 uA.

3'layer switches with X conductor, hole in sheet, y conductor  can be made arbitrarily  sensitive.
I used to make keyboards in this manner for disability aid use, suited for operation by a young child.

What is your desired on / off pressure and operating effector dimensions?

Comment: I hadn't heard of tactile dome switches before, if there was a NC version that would be perfect! 10uA is still 7x the total typical power consumption of my microcontroller, though significantly better than what I'm using now.

The on/off pressure being 1-2lbs of force would work fine. And effector diameter of no more than 1cm...I had switched to using this https://www.amazon.com/Pressure-Precise-Force-Sensitive-Resistor-Resistance-type/dp/B07T1CHY58/ref=sr_1_3

Comment: An NC dome switch would be quite unusual.

Answer (score 2):

Really appreciate all the answers from others on this question!

The solution I found ending up being pretty simple. Instead of connecting the force sensitive resistor to VCC and using an input pin configured to pull-down, I connected the resistor to ground and allowed the input pin to float.

Since the resistor isn't connected to VCC, there's no extra consumption to worry about. My typical power consumption is still 1.4uA for the whole MCU and it wakes up reliably! This setup would be problematic if you actually wanted to know the force applied, but I just need it to be a trigger to wake up from hibernation.

Here's the consumption while the resistor is pressed:[image]

And when I momentarily stop pressing it, I get a spike which triggers waking up